# Windows Mount Timeouts

Tags: windows-vista, mount, linux-mint

I have a Windows Vista share mounted onto a Linux Mint 17 laptop.  If I go too long without using the share, the mount times out and I can no longer access any files from the Windows machine.  The only way to reconnect is if I restart the Linux machine.

I can prevent this by running a script that writes to a temp file in the share every hour, and this keeps the mount active.  Is there a better way to prevent the problem, and is there a way to fix it other than restarting the computer?